# Why is the method resolution order in groovy non-standard?

Tags: groovy

Using traits, you can model multiple inheritance in groovy. Consider the following code, where a simple diamond is modelled using A,B,C, and X. Furthermore trait F serves as a end point.

```
trait A {
    def f() {
        println("A")
        super.f()
    }
}

trait B extends A {
    def f() {
        println("B")
        super.f()
    }
}

trait C extends A {
    def f() {
        println("C")
        super.f()
    }
}

trait F {
    def f() { println("F") }
}

class X implements F,B,C { }


def x = new X()
x.f()
```

The output of this programm is:

```
C
A
B
F
```

Notice that `A.f` is called *before* `B.f` despite `A` being a superclass of `B`. So a superclass method is called before the subclass method. This seems all wrong.

In Python, Scala, and Common Lisp the output of similar code would be `C B A F`, which is AFAIK known as [C3 Linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization).

What is the intention behind this choice of method resolution order, or is it simply just a bug in groovy (2.4.6)?

Answer (score 0):

That's the order defined [in the documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_chaining_behavior)

And there's another bit in the [section about conflict resolution](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_multiple_inheritance_conflicts)

It's not a bug

Comment: Both URLs are dead now and no content was cited in the answer

Comment: Links fixed... The content is quite extensive to meaningfully cite